# Export Hive database, All tables and columns names, to text or csv

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive

There are about 240 tables in a Hive database on AWS. I want to export all tables with column names and their data types to a csv. How can I do that?

Comment: Add an example of a table and the requested output

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz I am looking for a generic process to export tables using Hive. Please see the answer below. Jyoti understood my question and her response is what I was looking for.

Comment: 1. Do you see data types anywhere? 2. Export and then what? 3. Tables sizes?

Comment: Just the column names for analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use-

```
hive -e 'set hive.cli.print.header=true; SELECT * FROM db1.Table1' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > /home/table1.csv
```

`set hive.cli.print.header=true` : This will add the column names in the csv file

`SELECT * FROM db1.Table1`: Here, you have to provide your query.

`/home/table1.csv`: Path where you want to save the file (here as table1.csv).

Hope this solve your problem!

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful